# Laravel - Carbon Macro Call to undefined Method

Tags: php, laravel, macros, php-carbon

I created a `CarbonServiceProvider` class using `php artisan make:provider CarbonServiceProvider` and added it in the `providers` array in my `app.php` file.

In the `boot()` method I added this macro:

```
public function boot()
{
    if(!Carbon::hasMacro('nextWorkingDaySameTime')){
        Carbon::macro('nextWorkingDaySameTime', function ($startHour = 8, $endHour = 17) {
            [...]

            return $this;
        });
    }
}
```

I paid attention to use `Illuminate\Support\Carbon;` instead of `Carbon\Carbon`, since then it says that `macro()` would be undefined.

Whenever I call this macro like so:

`\Carbon\Carbon::nextWorkingDaySameTime();`

it fails with the following message:

`Call to undefined method Carbon\Carbon::nextWorkingDaySameTime()`

Comment: **I paid attention to use Illuminate\Support\Carbon; instead of Carbon\Carbon** - don't you also need to do the same when *calling* your macro? It looks like you're trying to run it on the `Carbon` class itself

Comment: You may need to do `composer dump-autoload` I guess. And I think `Carbon\Carbon` should do the job instead

Comment: @iainn Hm, good catch. I've tried it with the other class but it ends up in telling me `Using $this when not in object context` even when I instantly `return $this` without modifying anything.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin This ends up in `Call to undefined method Carbon\Carbon::hasMacro()
` even after dumping composer autoload...

Comment: What do you expect `$this` to be? Because as the error mentions you are at that point not in a class scope, so you can not use `$this` there

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I expect `$this` to be a Carbon Date, since I call the macro using `Carbon::now()->myMacro()` so in that case `Carbon::now()` should be `$this`. They do the same in their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that you're calling `\Carbon\Carbon::nextWorkingDaySameTime();`
You should call `\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::nextWorkingDaySameTime();` instead.